# Remove all Non-Alphanumeric Characters from a variable which store a output of an unmarshal function

Tags: go

I parse and store JSON data via the package json and use the func Unmarshal to get my desired output. 
Unfortunately the output I get is:

&{6}

and I only want

6.

Here some of my code:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Total      int    `json:"total"`
}

func getStations(body []byte) (*AutoGenerated, error) {
    var s = new(AutoGenerated)
    err := json.Unmarshal(body, &s)
    if(err != nil){
                fmt.Println("whoops:", err)
    }
    return s, err
}

func main() {
    s, err := getStations([]byte(body))

    fmt.Printf("%v, %T", s, s)

    s, err := getStations([]byte(body))
}
```

I can't use the reg.ReplaceAllString function in the package regexp because this is no string. It seems to be a pointer or something. body stores the json.

Comment: If you don't want the whole struct, don't print the whole struct. Print just s.Total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue you got is about formating verbs - `%v` - will show you verbose way how your variable looks like. You also can try to use `%+v` and `%#v`, but what you need is `%s` (if stringer implemented) or call a struct field, as far as I see and guess.

---

- `&{6}` is only pointer to struct with number 6 in it (`%v` with represent it in this way).
- `&{%!s(int=6)}` - this you will get if you will try to use `%s` on a struct that doesn't have Stringer interface implementation.
- `&{field:6}` - `%+v` will generate also field name of the struct.
- `&struct { v int }{v:6}` this shows (my example) a struct name and package and value - thats for `%#v`.

I would suggest to call struct field directly.

```
func main() {
    s := &struct {
        v int
    }{6}
    fmt.Printf("%d", s.v)
}
```

Outputs `6`, but you need to call field instead of the struct.